# Existence of an inner product under which all elements of a finite subgroup of $GL(V)$ are isometries

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, linear-transformations, inner-products, isometry

I'm currently hopelessly stuck on an exercise in linear algebra and I could use some hints.

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space over the reals and let $G$ be a finite subgroup of $$\operatorname{GL}(V):=\{f:V\to V\,|\,f\text{ is linear and bijective}\}.$$
**Prove:** There exists an inner product $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle:V\times V\to\mathbb R$ under which all $f\in G$ are isometries, i.e.
$$\langle f(\mathbf v),f(\mathbf w)\rangle=\langle\mathbf v,\mathbf w\rangle\quad\forall\ f\in G,\mathbf v,\mathbf w\in V.$$

Comment: Just take any inner product $g$ and average over all elements of $G$, that is, the product of $x$ and $y$ will be $\sum_{a\in G} g(ax,ay)$. It is a common trick (and works for compact subgroups as well).

Comment: @PeterFranek I see what you mean, but right now I don't see how I could prove that this makes any $f$ an isometry, that is, how would I prove $\sum_{a\in G}g(afx,afy)=\sum_{a\in G}g(ax,ay)$?

Comment: @PeterFranek Oh, I think now I see... since $G$ is finite, we can conclude that the sums must be identical, right? (Got it - if I'm not mistaken, $G\to G, a\mapsto af$ is a bijection. Thanks for your hint!)

Comment: In order to rectify my argumentation: Of course $a\mapsto af$ is a bijection no matter if $G$ is finite or infinite, but since $G$ is finite, we can evaluate the sum.